# Razor - write unique tag into <body>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am follwing this dom-based routing for kicking off specific javascript on each page
http://viget.com/inspire/extending-paul-irishs-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution

So need to write a unique data attribute into the  tag each time a page loads

e.g.

```
<body data-controller="Home" data-action="Index">
```

What's the best place to put this logic for a razor view?

The body tag is in my masterpage (_layout.cshtml) file. And it needs to dynamically render that on each page

Was thinking of overriding OnActionExecuting in a base controller and have that inject the current controller and action name into the ViewBag. Then referencing the ViewBag properties in my _layout.cshtml

Does that make sense or is there a more appropriate place for this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass the data through `ViewBag` (although it could work), instead of you can access the current controller and action through the `ViewContext` property in any View (even in Layout)

```
<body 
   data-controller="@(ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"])" 
   data-action="@(ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"])">
```

For setting other "global properties" on the `ViewBag` the `OnActionExecuting` (maybe combined with a base class or using a custom a filter) is the right place.